# How do I make sections in Navigation drawer - Android

Tags: java, android

Simply put, how do I make this?

[image: Check the sections.]

I have already created a navigation drawer with items but I don't know how do I make the sections.

Comment: Question not understandable. Provide more details. What is `notification drawer` did you mean `navigation drawer`?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry - typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, I think what you want to to is a `NavigationDrawer`, right ? take a look at the doc and simple implementation here :

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

To create section in it, you just put a standard list with section in it.
A lot a sample in here for that :

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Or use a lib :

https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview